# I always get Error 404 and some of my pages disappeared specially the homepage

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I badly need help. I always get Error 404 and some of my pages disappeared specially the homepage. I already fixed the error thru permalinks and .htaccess but still I get error 404. Is there any other way to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: When asking for help, please include the maximum technical details. Did this start overnight or after some update? *"I already fixed"*, how did you fix it? Did you check your error logs? Did you take any other debugging step? [so] and [wordpress.se] have lots and lots of similar questions, what did you find and what solutions did you try? Check [this results](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+permalinks+site%3Astackoverflow.com), I'm positive you'll find a solution in one of those posts.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take a few moments to review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Permalink settings select "post name" radio button then save permalink.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Permalinks, and click save changes.

Make sure you choose the correct permalink structure.